# How to pass token and input parameters when using Threadpool?

Tags: c#, multithreading

How can I pass several parameters when using Threadpool? I would like to do something similar to PerformTest(true, 3, 2, _cancellationTokenSourceObj.Token)

This is how I am using it passing only the token for cancellation:

```
_cancellationTokenSourceObj = new CancellationTokenSource();
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(PerformTest), _cancellationTokenSourceObj.Token);
```

PerformTest Method:

```
 public void PerformTest(object obj)
     {
         CancellationToken token = (CancellationToken)obj;
        ..
      }
```

Comment: Why QueueUserWorkItem and not a Task?

Answer (score 0):

If you use an anonymous function, it will work as a closure and have access to variables in your local scope.

```
bool arg0 = true;
int arg1 = 3;
int arg2 = 2;
CancellationTokenSource cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(obj =>
{
    CancellationToken token = (CancellationToken)obj;
    // PerformTest body here
    // This anonymous delegate is a closure and has access to arg0, arg1, and arg2.
}, cancelTokenSource.Token);
```

If you want to continue to use a named function, you will need to create a data structure for your arguments, plus the cancellation token, and cast it from the object argument in your named function.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using this obsolete API:

```
_cancellationTokenSourceObj = new CancellationTokenSource();
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(() => PerformTest(_cancellationTokenSourceObj.Token));
```

Better use `Task.Run`.